# Flutter :swift compiler error: cannot infer contextual base in reference member -Edit#2

Tags: ios, flutter, simulator

I have a mobile app created by Flutter. I want to run it on iOS Simulator on Mac, the app stopped work on startup as shown in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aa26OdOZJ2Y&feature=youtu.be

### When I start open project with XCode I get this :  swift compiler error: cannot infer contextual base in reference member as show in first image

[image]

### When I run the app on XCode I get this  error :

[image]

[image]

Is there any suggested solution?

Comment: Open `ios` folder in Xcode and run from there. It will show you the error.

Comment: if it is possible can you tell me which iOS I must select in : IOS Deployment target

Comment: I add detail on question

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by click on ( Command + Shift + k ) keys then run it and worked correctly